# Failed to load C++ bson extension, using pure JS version error when running mongodb-backed node app

Tags: xcode, node.js, mongodb

I get the aforementioned error every time I run a node app that requires `mongodb`. All my apps run fine as before, though the pure JS version is apparently slower.

I've scoured stackoverflow and github issue pages to try and solve my issue, but none of the suggestions I've tried work.

I've run mongodb-backed node apps in the past before without hitches. However, I recently uninstalled Xcode using [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) a week ago (scans and deletes leftover files), which might be the culprit.

### My attempts at solving the problem (I ran a sample node app after every step to check if it works)

Note: `xcode-select --install` says that it's already installed

1. `npm update`
2. `rm -rf node_modules`, `npm cache clean`, `npm install`
3. `sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
4. `npm install -g node-gyp` followed by `sudo node-gyp rebuild` inside the bson dir inside the mongodb dir located in my app's node_modules. This fails catastrophically, shown here http://pastebin.ca/3011137
5. Install Xcode again
6. `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Here is the package.json for my app

```
{
"name": "hw1-3",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Homework 1.3",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "consolidate": "~0.9.1",
    "crypto": "~0.0.3",
    "express": "3.x",
    "mongodb": "~1.3.11",
    "swig": "~0.14.0"
  },
  "author": "You",
  "license": "BSD",
  "private": true
}
```

npm output after running `rm -rf node_modules`, `npm cache clean`, `npm install`

```
npm WARN deprecated swig@0.14.0: v1.0.0 is a complete rewrite of Swig from the ground up. Previous versions are no longer supported
 
> kerberos@0.0.3 install /Users/prashanthcr/Programming/M101JS/week_1_introduction/homework_1_3/hw1-3/hw1-3/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o

> bson@0.2.5 install /Users/prashanthcr/Programming/M101JS/week_1_introduction/homework_1_3/hw1-3/hw1-3/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
consolidate@0.9.1 node_modules/consolidate

crypto@0.0.3 node_modules/crypto

swig@0.14.0 node_modules/swig
└── underscore@1.8.3

express@3.20.3 node_modules/express
├── basic-auth@1.0.0
├── merge-descriptors@1.0.0
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── cookie-signature@1.0.6
├── methods@1.1.1
├── cookie@0.1.2
├── escape-html@1.0.1
├── fresh@0.2.4
├── range-parser@1.0.2
├── content-type@1.0.1
├── vary@1.0.0
├── parseurl@1.3.0
├── content-disposition@0.5.0
├── commander@2.6.0
├── depd@1.0.1
├── mkdirp@0.5.0 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── proxy-addr@1.0.8 (forwarded@0.1.0, ipaddr.js@1.0.1)
├── debug@2.2.0 (ms@0.7.1)
├── etag@1.5.1 (crc@3.2.1)
├── send@0.12.3 (destroy@1.0.3, ms@0.7.1, mime@1.3.4, etag@1.6.0, on-finished@2.2.1)
└── connect@2.29.2 (pause@0.0.1, response-time@2.3.1, vhost@3.0.0, on-headers@1.0.0, basic-auth-connect@1.0.0, bytes@1.0.0, method-override@2.3.3, serve-static@1.9.3, connect-timeout@1.6.2, qs@2.4.2, cookie-parser@1.3.5, finalhandler@0.3.6, http-errors@1.3.1, morgan@1.5.3, serve-favicon@2.2.1, express-session@1.10.4, body-parser@1.12.4, multiparty@3.3.2, type-is@1.6.2, csurf@1.7.0, compression@1.4.4, errorhandler@1.3.6, serve-index@1.6.4)

mongodb@1.3.23 node_modules/mongodb
├── kerberos@0.0.3
└── bson@0.2.5
```

Running on Mac OS X 10.10.3

Comment: You should post the actual log you get from npm.

Comment: I added the npm output as stated. If that isn't the log you were looking for, my apologies, let me know where I can find it

Comment: The log you posted does not show the error you described in your question. It looks like it compiled successfully to me.

Comment: Where do I get the log I need? The only output I get when running my app.js is `Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version`, and a `console.log()` statement that I put in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are depending on an old version of `mongodb` which in turn is depending on an old version of `bson` which probably lacks (complete) support for node v0.12+.

The current version of `mongodb` is 2.0.33 as of this writing. Try using that instead and it *should* work fine.

On an unrelated note, the version of Express you're depending on (3.x) is old too, 4.x has been out for quite some time now.

Comment: I'm doing the M101JS course by MongoDB, unfortunately their app crashes if I use the latest one, so I'll have to live with this :(. Hopefully they get around to updating their courseware

Comment: Well, at least your dependencies should still work, it's just that `bson` will use a slower (js) parser.